# Vertical align middle a link without lineheight

Tags: css, hyperlink, alignment, line, vertical-alignment

Code&Preview: http://www.bootply.com/lixzKzFYxt

i want to get the link vertical middle in the blue stripe.

I read that is possible with lineheight but it will be hide a part of the link in the second box.

the link have this css selector `.rubrik-thumbnail .caption a:first-child {}`

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my Solution:

```
display:flex;
algin-items:center;
height:60px;
```

Answer (score 0):

***CSS***

```
.rubrik-thumbnail .caption a:first-child{
        top:30%;
     }
```

[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/lixzKzFYxt#)

Comment: Your Demolink is the same like in my post.. u need to Fork to get a link with the changes. 
Here http://www.bootply.com/4xvWgom2iL
Thats not really vertical middle...